# AWS Lambda: backup everything to local

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm creating a backup system for my lambda functions.

It should backup/download the layers, step functions, IAM policies, everything attached to each function to my local PC.

how do I implement this?

this source: https://disaster-recovery.workshop.aws/en/labs/basics/lambda.html#labs_types-1
is not enough because it only backups the function code as far as I'm concerned.

Thanks

Comment: You have this backwards. Revision-controlled assets (code, policies, automation, etc.) should be the source for your deployed application.

Answer (score 4):

AWS does not have a general "backup & restore" capability. Instead, it takes an "infrastructure as code" approach using **CloudFormation or Terraform templates**. These templates define the desired resources, which can then be deployed in a repeatable manner.

You could attempt to use https://former2.com/ to create a CloudFormation template based on existing resources, but it might not capture everything you have created.